# Exporting Chart with umlauts (ä)

Tags: highcharts

Is there a way to export a chart with umlauts in the axis labels? My chart has the german months (Januar, Februar, März ...) on the x-axis. The labels are configured via Highcharts.setOptions(). I used \u00e4 for the ä in "März", it's shown correctly on the website, but in the exported images it's always a displayed as a ?.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes it is possible, you need to UTF-8 encode in your file / page.

Comment: Is that the only way? That would be really bad, since the whole website is encoded in latin1.

Comment: Yes it is, or you can try to prepare your own server. UTF8 is the most popular encode which contains all marks, so that is the reason why we use it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, you need to UTF-8 encode in your file / page.